# Is it acceptable to think about dual vector space in terms of operations on different vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, dual-spaces

I'm looking into abstract algebra.

It seems like with actual examples of covectors, the things we do the vector space operations on (addition and scalar multiplication) are objects like: $\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\end{pmatrix}$ or $\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}$, but when treating them like maps there is, at least implicitly, an operation of matrix multiplication and a dot product involved (respectively).

I know the abstract definition of a dual vector space, but maybe I've having this confusion because I haven't been exposed to enough examples. At the risk of being pedantic, is thinking of a covector (or dual vector) as an element of a vector space and also an element of a structure in abstract algebra with an operation $\diamond$ present, say, such that $v^*\diamond w=k$ and $v^*$ is linear (k is some field element), common? You see, I basically am used to thinking of a lot of things in terms of Cayley tables, so it would make sense to me if the vectors from the dual space were on one axis of the Cayley table and vectors from the regular vector space were on the other, which would imply thinking about lots of covectors the way we do- involving an operation that has certain properties -yet I have not seen this anywhere. Is thinking of covectors as elements, under a certain operation, rather that a set of THE functions on a set, equivalent? I realize that this isn't standard, but does it work?

> **Problem: I'm confused about whether covectors are objects or maps - I understand that its perfectly sensible to define them in terms of maps, but in practice it seems like there is always an operation involved.**

> **Question: I'm looking for 1) confirmation that covectors as maps and covectors as parts of a Cayley Table (when defined up to isomorphism), are indeed equivalent [i.e. for some vector $\alpha$ is $\alpha$ together with the operation $\diamond$, or just $\alpha$ by itself the real covector we are talking about] and 2) why this is not the standard view [to think of covectors with an operation].**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicitly, you seem to be working with a vector space over a field, let's call it $V$ over $k$. A covector usually means an element of the dual space $V^*$, which is defined to be the set of linear maps $V\to k$. In particular, a covector is a type of linear map. The set of all such maps is $V^*$, and you can easily check that it has a structure of a vector space under pointwise addition and scaling. Moreover, when $V$ is finite dimensional, $V\cong V^*$.

If we take $V$ to have a basis $e_1,\ldots, e_n$, then $v=\sum_{i=1}^n v^ie_i$ has column vector representation
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
v^1\\
\vdots\\
v^n
\end{bmatrix}.$$
On the other hand, we can define a "dual" basis on $V^*$ to be $\phi^1,\ldots \phi^n$ so that
$$\phi^i(e_j)=
\begin{cases}
1&i=j\\
0&i\ne j.
\end{cases}
$$
Then it's clear that if $\phi=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\phi^j$ and $v$ is as above, we have $\phi(v)=\sum_{j=1}^n a_jv^j\in k.$ So, we can view this as multiplication
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1&\cdots&a_n
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
v^1\\
\vdots\\
v^n
\end{bmatrix}=\sum_j a_jv^j.
$$
In particular, we can regard a covector as a row vector as you wrote in the beginning of your post. The operation $\diamond$ you have defined is just the evaluation map $\phi\diamond v=\phi(v)$ like above. This isn't really an operation like in a group, but it does define a "bilinear" map $\diamond:V^*\times V\to k$ by $\diamond(\phi,v)=\phi(v)$. I don't think we should think of Cayley tables here. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for, thx! If I understand correctly, covectors are formally defined as maps but depending on what you're doing with them they manifest in different forms - e.g. if they're acting on something you may view them with, in certain cases, matricies or row vectors, but in others it is conventional to omit the operation to make things simpler (or at least this is what I presume based on the answer). Basically: *they may be viewed in different ways*. And the bit about Cayley tables makes sense I guess.

Comment: Even better: when we talk about covectors, sometimes we are talking about things naturally isomorphic to covectors. I gather that the exact notation used is somewhat informal; in most cases you can reference it as many things for what you're doing and it isn't too important exactly what you call it. The notation is flexible and whatever is convenient to represent the covectors at that moment.

Comment: And when we talk about such representations of dual vectors the 'operation' is implicit and occasionally obvious.The important part is that view them as elements of vector spaces.

Comment: For vectors viewed as 3D arrows, it is more common to think of the dual space as row vectors rather than column vectors with a dit product (is that right)? As long as the way in which something is a covectors is **natural** the notation doesn't matter (emphasizing natural)?

Comment: Typically $V$ is considered the column vectors, and $V^*$ the row vectors. However, this is completely an arbitrary choice. Indeed column vectors can be viewed as functionals on row vectors. In fact, $V^{**}$ is naturally isomorphic to $V$.

Comment: Ok, sorry to bother you again but I want to clarify one thing. If $\begin{bmatrix}1&4&-3\end{bmatrix}$ is a covector then technically since dual vectors are linear maps it would act on a vector as its input via $\begin{bmatrix}1&4&-3\end{bmatrix}\left(\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}\right)$; the evaluation map. But it doesn't act via an evaluation map, it acts via traditional matrix multiplication as such; $\begin{bmatrix}1&4&-3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$. Moreover, for another example in tensor analysis we have the contravariant basis $e^i$ and the [wait, I continu.]

Comment: covariant basis, $e_j$ - which is formally defined as the dual basis. Their relation is defined by in the expression $e^i\dot{}e_j$ (equalsing the kronecker delta). So, $e_j$ is (here) obviously a column vector. But doesn't that mean that you should write $\begin{bmatrix}1\\4\\-3\end{bmatrix}\left(\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}\right)$ again as if $\begin{bmatrix}1\\4\\-3\end{bmatrix}$ is a function acting on some input vector? But here again, the map being used isn't an evaluation map but a dot product; $\begin{bmatrix}1\\4\\-3\end{bmatrix}\dot{}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: So is this technically an abuse of notation? Essentially, covectors are defined using the evaluation map but neither of these common examples of dual vectors actually act using an evaluation map. So I guess it comes down to the concept of whether the evaluation map is a loosely defined thing and the dot product, for example, counts as an evaluation map, or whether saying that either of the examples above is an abuse of notation. I don't know which one it is.

Comment: After reading this (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Evaluation_Mapping though), which is a bit vague in itself with the f(t) notation I suppose, it feels unlikely that I am just interpreting the evaluation map wrong but idk that's just my intuition. So linking this back your answer (the purpose of comments is to ask for clarification), you said "we can view this as..." and "we can regard this as...", but can we really do that?

Comment: I don't see any formal justification that the evaluation map can be viewed as matrix multiplication - although I realize that this is standard to do. Surely, a single object can not be **formally** be defined as the set of all linear functionals AND an object which must act on the object using a matrix multiplication, a dot product, or more abstractly some other operation.

Comment: Ok I think this is it for now I won't ask anything else. I want to clarify with these comments one thing: is my conclusion that saying that the row or column vectors above are dual vectors an abuse of notation, correct (in other words it is true by abuse of notation)? Thank you!

Comment: Aggggghg hold up. Reading your answer you could just *define* $\phi$ by the property that $\phi (v)$ and $\phi\cdot v$ are the same thing. Is that right? Literally how have I missed this, I'm a fool. (I still would like confirmation that this is right though) anyways thank you !!

Comment: If $\phi$ is a linear functional represented as a row vector and $v$ is a vector represented as a column vector, $\phi(v)$ is equal to the multiplication of row vector by column vector as you say. In short, $\phi(v)$ makes sense as evaluation of a functional on a vector. Given a row vector, we _define_ its evaluation on a column vector by the matrix multiplication.

Comment: Wow this literally cleared up years of confusion! :) :) Nice.